# Ag-grid server-side pagination with Server-side Row Model

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to set up pagination for the server-side row model (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-pagination/). Unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems to be that the server-side row model uses a client-side pagination and not a real server-side pagination.

With the Infinite Row Model the server-side pagination is working fine, but there I can not use the Master Detail feature.

Is there a way to use both? Server-side pagination and master detail view? And I am using all enterprise features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ag-grid to a newer version solved this issue.